# Navigating through source code efficiently in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I was trying to find the method being called when `Item.where(dst: "video")` is called (Item being a Mongoid model). Looking up in the source code, I see that [criteria.rb](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/1f8e12c5b03da1c9bd49bab12d86bef969868fb3/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb) is the place to go to. However, `def where` calls super. Then `Origin::Selectable` (included inside `Origin::Queryable`) defines it:

```
def where(criterion = nil)
   criterion.is_a?(String) ? js_query(criterion) : expr_query(criterion)
end
```

Now, I would have to see where `js_query` and `expr_query` are, see what they do and so on.

It gets tough going through all this source code and modules, finding all the methods and then trying to figure out how it works.

Is there a better way to do this process to find out how things work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You want help navigating through code, but you don't say what you are using for your editor, and Stack Overflow isn't the place to ask for recommendations for editors, though existing legacy questions do give suggestions. Please describe what you are trying to do better, so we can help you. Also, though you refer to some Mongoid calls, that doesn't make the question a "gem" or a "mongoid" question. Please use tags that specifically apply to the question, not ones that are remotely associated with it.

Comment: Thanks for the review. I use Sublime Text 3, but my question was not focused on editors but more broadly.

Comment: Well, the broader question makes it harder to help you. You can tell by the two widely divergent answers so far, that we can't really tell what you are asking, which makes your question undesirable for the site. Please try to reword it and make it more clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the class of the receiver (say `A`) and the method name (say `foo`), then you can do:

```
A.instance_method(:foo).source_location
```

That will give the file name and the line number in most cases. If it returns `nil`, then it is likely a C-defined method, which does not rely on other Ruby methods.

Another way is to use the `pry` gem or the `method_source` gem.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to improve your editor experience. There are three remarkable abilities (besides many others like [Eclipse/Aptana](http://blog.robert.mcfrazier.com/setting-up-eclipse-for-ruby-development/), [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/ruby/index.html), etc):

- [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html) — not free, but probably the best one;
- [Atom Editor](https://atom.io) with [RSense plugin](https://atom.io/packages/rsense) — free (plugins are also available for [SublimeText](https://github.com/rsense/SublimeRsense) and [TextMate2](https://github.com/rsense/rsense.tmbundle);
- vim/emacs with `[c|e]tags`.

Depending on your choice you yield an ability to quickly navigate through your code with either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> or with your preferred keyboard shortcut.

Here on SO this question was asked an amount of times as well: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=best+ruby+editor

Hope it helps.

Comment: While this is attempting to help, it's important to mention there are MANY other editors with equal capabilities and that are equally well represented in the Ruby community. Comparisons and recommendations have occurred in other questions on the site, so those pages should be referenced.